# Any vector in $S^n(V)$ (symmetric algebra of vector space $V$) can be obtained as $\sum_{i}^{\text{finite}}v_i^n$ for $v_i\in V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $K$ algebraically closed. Let $S(V) = \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty S^n(V)$ is the symmetric algebra. I heard somewhere some time ago (I don't remember where) that:

> For any vector $u\in S^n(V)$ there exists a set of vectors in $V$, say $W_u=\{v_i\in V\}$, such that
>   $$
> u=\sum_{i=1}^{|W_u|} v_i^n
> $$
>   where $v_i^n$ is the $n$th symmetric power.

I tried to prove it and failed. I think there is some trick to this. Can anyone tell me how this is proved or disproved? Also if it true can we choose $W_u$ such that it is a finite set? Moreover is there any restriction on the characteristic of $K$ necessary for this statement? (I have a feeling that if this is true at all, it should only work for characteristic zero).

P.S. I'm having trouble tagging this question; linear algebra doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the hypothesis that $k$ has characteristic zero; if $k$ has characteristic $p$ then this is false for $n = p$. This is Lemma 2 in [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/four-flavors-of-schur-weyl-duality/). It's clear that you can choose $W$ to be finite since $S^n(V)$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Quick question: If $n=2k$ and $n\neq 2$, for a characteristic $p$ field, this still fails if $2k>p$, right?

Comment: @Hamed: I believe it fails iff $p$ divides $n$, although I'm not sure.

Comment: The things is the coefficients $n!/m_1!m_2!\cdots m_n!$ in lemma 2 will become zero somewhere if $n>p$. Although there might be some subtlety happening here. I'm not sure either.